# Delay in big files using Javascript native audio library

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

Heys guys!

I'm just trying to play an audio from a certain position using the **native audio class** and it works great in small audios (some seconds) but when I try the same in a 20 minutes audio, it plays with a delay of something about half a second, which is a lot for what I need.

I made a simple jsfiddle to illustrate this, I hope it helps to understand the problem.

Both positions, in the long and short audio, should play exactly the same but actually they don't. I also attach two screen captures to show that the position in the audio is the correct one.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oxmanroman/n4sLLuk9/4/

```
playShortAudio().then(() => {
    setTimeout(playLongAudio, 1000);
})

function playShortAudio() {
    // play from 2 seconds, 400 milliseconds
    return playAudio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/thespanishapp/test.mp3', 2.400);
}

function playLongAudio() {
    // play from 4 minutes, 27 seconds, 750 milliseconds
    return playAudio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/thespanishapp/large-test.mp3', 267.750);
}

function playAudio(url, startingPoint) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    const audio = new Audio(url);
    // set audio position to listen 'hello miss...'
    audio.currentTime = startingPoint;
    // play audio when ready
    audio.oncanplaythrough = () => {
      audio.play();
      // stop the audio and resolve the promise after two seconds of audio
      setTimeout(() => {
        audio.pause();
        resolve();
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's attributed to the time it takes to load the relevant files. You'll need to preload them if you want to start them at the same time.

Comment: Isn't it what canplaythrough event bind to? When the audio is loaded enough to play? I tried setting audio.preload = 'auto'; but still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact issue is the MP3 format.

The start time is correct, but **MP3 has "time drift"** which is worse in some browsers than others. I would strongly recommend using **AAC** (.m4a) format instead. It doesn't only remove the time drifting, but AAC also has better portability across browsers, both desktop and mobile.